# C - what is the pointer in the following program mean?

Tags: c, pointers

(This isn't my homework, but a revision paper that my teachers didn't provide any answers to.)

I have question which asks us to fill in 2 blanks in this following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
     int i, x[] = {-5,10,-10,-2,23,-20};
     char y[20] = "goodbye";
     char * p = y;
     for (i=0;i<6;i++){
         *(p+i)= /*blank*/ ;
     }
     y[6] = /*blank*/ ;
     printf("%s\n",p);
}
```

The output generated by the above program is `byebye`.

I would like to find out what `*(p+i)` means and the answers for the blanks?

Comment: `*(p+i)` is just an ugly way to write `p[i]`.

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`.

Comment: The answers for the blanks are your assignment, aren't they? Find what you need to fill in there to actually *get* `byebye` as an output, to show to your lecturer? Because as it is, the program doesn't even compile. We generally don't solve someone's assignment / homework. You got the meaning of `*(p + i)` explained to you; that's as far as we should go at this point. ;-)

Comment: I'll give you a hint. The `%` operator will be helpful in the loop...

Comment: @DevSolar Good hint! Another one, strings in c are arrays of characters terminated with a `'\0'` character (*aka the `null` byte*).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a study assignment, and unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That doesn't mean that you should post the answer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: You think he's learning more from reading the answer than figuring it out himself?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Also, you seem to forget that what seems very simple to you is not necessarily simple to someone with less experience and knowledge? That's the whole point of *learning*.

Comment: Guys, it is more a puzzle than a learning excercise. But OK, removed my answer. Indeed I sometimes myself get a bit upset with people providing answers for homework. I even got downvoted once for _not_ providing the homework excercise's answer but gave a learning discussion. Hope his teacher will give more meaningful excercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression like this

```
y[i]
```

is calculated by the compiler (according to the C Standard) using the pointer arithmetic like

```
*( y + i )
```

So in the program you just substituted `y` for the variable `p`.

It seems the program should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i, x[] = { -5, 10, -10, -2, 23, -20 };
    char y[20] = "goodbye";
    char * p = y;

    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        *( p + i ) = *( p + i ) + x[i];
    }

    y[6] = '\0';

    printf( "%s\n", p );

    return 0;
}
```

You could for example the expression `x[i]` substitute for `*( x + i )`. That is this statement

```
*( p + i ) = *( p + i ) + x[i];
```

can be written like

```
y[i] = y[i] + x[i];
```

or

```
p[i] = p[i] + x[i];
```

or

```
*( y + i ) = y[i] + x[i];
```

or

```
*( p + i ) = y[i] + x[i];
```

or

```
*( p + i ) = *( p + i ) + *( x + i );
```

and so on.

Pay attention to that the magic number 6 in the for loop is confusing.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
                ^^^
```

It would be better to write at least like

```
const size_t N = sizeof( x ) / sizeof( *x );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
//...
y[N] = '\0';
```

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Your answer was also enough good.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a nice explanation!